# Running bash file from Java is not working

Tags: java, bash, shell, ubuntu

```
try{

        //String[] cmd = new String[]{"/bin/sh", "send.sh"};
        //Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);  //nothing happens           
        //Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("send.sh"); //File not found
        //Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("bash send.sh"); //nothing happens

        // ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("bash","send.sh");
        // Process p = pb.start(); //nothing happens

    }
    catch(Throwable t)
    {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
```

With this code I am trying to start a simple bash file which is located in the directory of the program. The code of the bash file works when I start it with shell or by simply executing it. The code of the bash file works.

I've tried every option but they are all not working. I've commented what happens in each case. I don't understand that it don't find the file because the bash file is located in the same directory.

Comment: What does "nothing happens" mean? Do you expect the output of the bash script to be printed to standard out? If so, that will not happen without some more code.

Comment: There is some space for more experiments. An example of them would be starting up an interactive shell (instead of trying to run a script immediately), and another one would be providing full path for the script.

Comment: Also, first you may want to have something in that script which can work for sure, like echoing something into a file, like /tmp/my.test

Comment: Your code is not working because it's all commented out.

Comment: @Andreas, lol. Yeah, that is the issue, indeed.

Comment: Of course i uncommented every line when i tried it^^the bash file controls a sending module whichs sends to a remote power plug. Im not at home but i will try this. Thanks . I will report

Answer (score 4):

You don't see an output for two reasons:

1. You don't wait for a process to finish
2. You don't redirect it's output to the same console that your Java process runs

And, probably, you need to use a command like `/bin/bash -c path/to/your/file.sh`. Note that **`-c`** flag.

IMHO, the best way to craft and execute external processes in Java is [`java.lang.ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).

Supposing that you have your `sh` file somewhere the in `resources` directory, here is an example main class:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", App.class.getResource("/46964369.sh").getPath());

        processBuilder.redirectInput(Redirect.INHERIT);
        processBuilder.redirectOutput(Redirect.INHERIT);
        processBuilder.redirectError(Redirect.INHERIT);

        processBuilder.start().waitFor();
    }
}
```

Note that I redirect process's streams with [`redirect*`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectOutput--) methods. `Redirect.INHERIT` redirects stream to the corresponding stream of the JVM instance. It works both for input and output streams. Finally, I am waiting for a process to finish with [`waitFor()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor--) method. In fact, you can do more, like capturing the output into a string, providing input from a string or running the process asynchronously, but this is a minimal example.

If you store your `sh` file in another place, you must update path-related logic.

Take a look at the complete example [here](https://github.com/madhead/playgrounds/tree/master/46964369). It's a Gradle project, and you can use `./gradlew run` to execute it:

```
$ ./gradlew run
:compileJava
:processResources
:classes
:run
Hello, world!

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 4s
3 actionable tasks: 3 executed
```

Comment: I will try that when im back home. The sh file is located in the directory of the program. I think your code will work thanks a lot. I will report if it works.

Comment: And, yes, you can specify a **working directory** for a process as well, so it will know where to resolve files.

Comment: sry that it took so long. okay i tried that example. i replaced the file in your example with my file. but now it just says that the file does not exist! its not hidden and i gave full access to it. what can it be?

Comment: /bin/bash: /home/pi/Documents/Java/BlueJ%20Projects/Trashprojects/shell/send.sh: file or path not found. (Translated from German)

Comment: I forgot to mention: Im working on a raspberry pi with ubuntu

Comment: and the file send.sh is in the programm directory (shell).

Comment: Are you sure that mentioned file exists? BTW, what are that special symbols in the middle?

Comment: yes im sure! you mean "Bluej%20Projects"? its weird because when im using the shell to change the directory to "shell" it wont because it says the path does not exist. i also tried it without those special symbols.      then placed the whole program directory on the desktop. then it kind of worked. but then i get a different error: it is complaining about the code inside the bash file man wtf?! the file is working when i start it manually. and btw why does java give sth for the code inside the bash? thats weird:/ ....man im just trying to start a simply bashfile :x :D

Comment: so does that mean that java is taking part of the actual shell? and thats why it complains about error inside the bash? because java is trying to compile bash script?

Comment: @gtxxtg, please, create another question with bash contents and the error you get.

Comment: here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47077338/starting-bash-file-from-java-wont-work