# Starting bash file from Java wont work

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell, process

in the java file i created a function which starts a bash file. i tried different ways but none of them work. i commented every method to show you
what ive already tried. Next to it is a short description what happens when i start the program.

java file:

```
try{

        //String[] cmd = new String[]{"/bin/sh", "send.sh"};
        //Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);  //nothing happens           
        //Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("send.sh"); //File not found
        //Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("bash send.sh"); //nothing happens

        // ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("bash","send.sh");
        // Process p = pb.start(); //nothing happens

        /*final ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", Klasse.class.getResource("./send.sh").getPath());
        processBuilder.redirectInput(Redirect.INHERIT);
        processBuilder.redirectOutput(Redirect.INHERIT);
        processBuilder.redirectError(Redirect.INHERIT);

        processBuilder.start().waitFor();*/
        //Error with the code in bash file

    }
    catch(Throwable t)
    {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
```

bash file:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd
cd rcswitch-pi
cd 433Utils/RPi_utils
sudo ./codesend 11782159
```

the bash file contains a way to send a code (11782159) via a transmitter. the transmitter sends the code to an outlet. THE BASH FILE WORKS! It works when i start it manually(without java. just by executing it)
The outlet changes its state so it works indeed.

the bash file is in the directory of the program file.
I took exactly the right name for the bash file.

Now i just want to start that bash file via java. Anybody can help pleas? its 
weird  because this problem doesnt seem that difficult but actually i just dont get the error.

Comment: What if you write the full path to the bash script?

Comment: Im working with ubuntu on a raspberry pi

Comment: Does the `Java` user have permissions to run `sudo` `shell` commands?  -- You must edit the `sudoers` file and allow the `Java` user `sudo` access without a password

Comment: If you start it manually, do you `cd` to a certain directory that contains the script?

Comment: His `user` has `sudo` access I am sure ..  Therefor it WILL run manually.

Comment: Try having a `test.sh` file which just prints "test", then try using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("bash test.sh");` and see if it prints.  If it does then the command on java's end is fine

Comment: phflack yes that works with the last opportunity! so how do i run these commands in the file "send.sh" via the java console?  or is there just opportunity to run the bash file seperate from the java process?

Comment: i tried to run the java program with starting a bash file that creates a directory. that worked! it worked with those ways which didnt work.i I just dont get why its a difference when i create a directory or when i want to send code via transmitter.

Comment: Anyone Sho knows?